# Surpress node request messages in Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have such output in my console, when running my Mocha test suite:

```
POST /user/signup 201 56.377 ms - 598
    ✓ should create a new user and login (57ms)
```

For readability reasons I want be able to surpress this part:

`POST /user/signup 201 56.377 ms - 598`

How is that possible, if at all?

Comment: Stack Overflow editorial practices do not allow answers in questions. If you want to submit an answer, please post it as an answer, not as an edit to a question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using express and a request logger middleware like morgan, can you check if it is in dev?

something like: `app.use(morgan('dev'));`

**Edit:**
as Sir Ben Benji says, the messages can be skipped with `skip` property

`// EXAMPLE: only log error responses
morgan('combined', {
  skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode < 400 }
})`

**source:** https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#skip

Comment: Ok I am doing now `morgan 'dev', skip: (req, res) ->
      res.statusCode < 400`, which skips (to log to console) everything, which is strange since, I got 404 and 500 incoming in my tests. Anyway you pointed me in the correct direction, thus I am giving you the answer.